# How to set value to cell in grid in extjs

Tags: extjs

I need to set value to particular cell from outside of grid.

My value is in session and i want to set this value to a cell in 2nd column and 0th row.
How i can do this in extjs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you must use the store associated with your grid

```
var grid = ...
var models = grid.getStore().getRange();
models[0].set(fieldName, "new value");
```

Comment: ei guys, I know this is an old post but I tries the solution above but did not work for me. I keep on getting this error saying "TypeError: source is null" May I see how you setup your grid and store of the grid?? thanks